# Create and Highlight element using For of Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How we can create elements in the loop?. I have positions with me and on page load, I want to highlight words at those positions by wrapping  Tags.  Below is my code

```js
function highlight(element,st,en){
    range = document.createRange();
    start = st;
    end = en;
    dig(element);
    s.addRange(range);
}
  

for (x of data) {
    var nameArr = jsondata.split(',');
    var a = nameArr[0];
    var b = nameArr[1];
    highlight($('.main-detail-content'), a, b);
    var ra = s.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("em");
    newNode.appendChild(ra.extractContents());
    ra.insertNode(newNode);
}
```

It only highlights one word but in loop, I have 4 records. Help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi can, you also share how data looks like?

Comment: Can you also add your html code to make it clear?

Comment: and i x i have data like positions example: 0 => 121,145 1=> [14,19] so words at these positions i have to highlight but in my case <em> tag is adding only at one place.

Comment: as you can see I am calling the highlight function but after that how do I create elements in the loop this is an issue. Sorry but I cannot use React and Angular n all

Comment: is data an array or an object?

Answer (score 0):

data is an Array like:

```
[
  "162,170",
  "83,91"
]
```

it looks like you are misusing the `for (x of data)` loop, as you are never using the x variable.

you should do something like:

```
//need a counter like variable to look at a different selection at every loop
var selectionIterator = 0;

for (var x of data) {
    var nameArr = data[x].split(',');
    console.log('when x is', x);
    console.log('nameArr is', nameArr);

    var a = nameArr[0];
    var b = nameArr[1];
    highlight($('.main-detail-content'), a, b);
    //now it's looking at the last selection every time
    var ra = s.getRangeAt(selectionIterator++);
    var newNode = document.createElement("em");
    newNode.appendChild(ra.extractContents());
    ra.insertNode(newNode);
}
```

this way nameArr at every iteration of the loop will change to the next element in the object, I have inserted a couple of console logs that may help you in debugging

EDIT:
By looking at your logs it looks that now it is properly iterating over the data array.

Also it's highlighting only the first word because you are adding the new node only at the first selection where you are doing `var ra = s.getRangeAt(0);` instead of having 0 hardcoded you should increment the counter every time that's why I'm introducing the `selectionIterator` variable.

It's not the most elegant solution but it should do the job

Comment: Hii Thank you for reply but data is array in my case and it giving error like cannot read property split of undefined

Comment: can you do a console.log(data) and paste it here?

Comment: This code is running but not highlighting words  for (var x of data) 
   {
    alert();
    var jsondata = x + '';
    var nameArr = jsondata.split(',');
    console.log('when x is', x);
    console.log('nameArr is', nameArr);

    var a = nameArr[0];
    var b = nameArr[1];
    highlight($('.main-detail-content'), a, b);
    var ra = s.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("em");
    newNode.appendChild(ra.extractContents());
    ra.insertNode(newNode);
   }

Comment: when x is 162,170
143748:5292 nameArr is (2) ["162", "170"]
143748:5291 when x is 83,91
143748:5292 nameArr is (2) ["83", "91"]

Comment: hii @brein code is running fine but again only highlighting only first one

Comment: After console.log(data);    data is:            ["162,170", "83,91"]

Comment: ok, now it looks clear, give me a sec and i will edit my answer

Comment: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 1 is not a valid index.     Giving this error

Comment: and again only the first word is being  highlighted.

Comment: Hii @brein it's saying 1 is not a valid index for getRangeAt. Now, what should I do?  plz help

Comment: getRangeAt not allowing to pass any other value except 0